# warning in Random Excursion test

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, nist, statistical-test

```
      RANDOM EXCURSIONS TEST
    --------------------------------------------
    COMPUTATIONAL INFORMATION:
    --------------------------------------------
    (a) Number Of Cycles (J) = 0106
    (b) Sequence Length (n)  = 10000
    ---------------------------------------------
    WARNING:  TEST NOT APPLICABLE.  THERE ARE AN
          INSUFFICIENT NUMBER OF CYCLES.
    ------------------------------------------
```

Why is this showing up ?  I used the recomended control set from the user guide in   http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit what this question is about? As it currently stand it is very unclear.

Comment: I think this question belongs in here and on topic, hence should be reopened. It needs rewording to make it clearer but it's a right question...